# Addresses not showing in walklist

Tags: civireport, custom-reports

I tried following this guide: https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/civic-engagement/everyday-tasks/

And created my surveys and reserved respondents but for some reason when we generate the report it only shows the name, and street number, and name is blank. Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be? I've also tried to re-install CiviCRM.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 2):

Steps I followed on Demo site now to test were

- confirm you have turned on address parsing by clicking on Administer > Administration Console> Configuration Checklist > Address Settings, then in the Address Editing area, check the box for Street Address Parsing.)
- confirm you have Scheduled Job for Geocode and Parse Addresses running at civicrm/admin/job?reset=1
- create New Campaign civicrm/campaign/add?reset=1
- create new Survey
- reserve some respondents
- go to All Reports, find one you created above from
- should see the Parsed address fields display results (in my case at this report for next few hours http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/38)

I suspect you might have not run your Geocode and Parse Address job.

hth